# Mongoose insertMany does not work for large array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have been trying to insert large data about(400-1000) json object array to mongodb using `mongoose` + `expressjs` When i changed data about(50) items insertMany works great without problem. But if data is more than 100 it giving me an error.

```
Departed.insertMany(results)
  .then(dep => {
    console.log(dep)
    res.sendStatus(201)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

in morgan console i got following:

```
creation { active: true,
  _id: 5b73e8af19722d1689d863b0,
  name: 'TEST DATA 241',
  map: '',
  created_at: 2018-08-15T08:47:43.196Z,
  updated_at: 2018-08-15T08:47:43.196Z,
  __v: 0 }
insert read 453
(node:5769) [DEP0079] DeprecationWarning: Custom inspection function on Objects via .inspect() is deprecated
```

also on client side(chrome, dev tools network tab) status got

```
(failed)
net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

I have read mongo's `insertMany()` has limit about 1000 and i am using mongo 4.0 version. Even i chunked large json into several arrays and tried to insert it but still got same results. Actual snippets are

```
router.post('/xls', upload.single('file'), async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (req.body && req.file) {
      console.log('req', req.file)
      const segments = req.file.originalname.split('.')
      let exceltojson = segments[segments.length - 1] === 'xlsx' ? xlsx : xls
      exceltojson(
        {
          input: req.file.path,
          output: 'output.json'
        },
        async (err, result) => {
          if (err) console.log(err)
          const section = await Section.create({
            name: req.body.section,
            map: req.body.map
          })
          const results = await result.map(item => {
            return {
              branch: req.body.branch,
              section: String(section._id),
              ...item
            }
          })
          await console.log('creation', section)
          console.log('insert read', results.length)
          if (results.length >= 100) {
            console.log('more than 100')
            const data = _.chunk(results, 100)
            data.forEach(async chunk => {
              console.log('foreach')
              Departed.insertMany(chunk)
                .then(dep => {
                  console.log(dep)
                  res.sendStatus(201)
                })
                .catch(err => {
                  console.log(err)
                })
            })
          }
        }
      )
    }
  } catch (error) {
    next(error)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not related to any `insertMany` limit. You have a race condition in your code where you don't wait for all chunks to be inserted, before sending the status back:

```
data.forEach(async chunk => {
  console.log('foreach')
  Departed.insertMany(chunk)
    .then(dep => { // this will be called as soon as one of the inserts finish
      console.log(dep)
      res.sendStatus(201)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
})
```

Change this in something like (untested):

```
Promise.all(data.map(chunk => Departed.insertMany(chunk)))
    .then(dep => { // this will be called when all inserts finish
      console.log(dep)
      res.sendStatus(201)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
})
```

Comment: still the same results. Also, response is (failed)
net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE too. Data is not written though.

Comment: Invalid op passed to `bulkWrite()`

Comment: I thought the same thing, like my insertion is not even finished then i am trying to send response but thing is keep saying and i wrapped all with `Promise`

Comment: Sorry I was confused with above posts

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use the [`bulkWrite`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite) API which is is faster than sending multiple independent operations because with [`bulkWrite()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite) there is only one round trip to MongoDB:

```
router.post('/xls', upload.single('file'), async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        if (req.body && req.file) {
            console.log('req', req.file)
            const segments = req.file.originalname.split('.')
            let exceltojson = segments[segments.length - 1] === 'xlsx' ? xlsx : xls
            exceltojson(
                {
                    input: req.file.path,
                    output: 'output.json'
                },
                async (err, result) => {
                    if (err) console.log(err)
                    const section = await Section.create({
                        name: req.body.section,
                        map: req.body.map
                    })

                    let chunk = [];

                    result.forEach(item => {
                        chunk.push({
                            insertOne: {
                                document: {
                                    branch: req.body.branch,
                                    section: String(section._id),
                                    ...item
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        if (chunk.length === 500) {
                            const blkResult = await Departed.bulkWrite(chunk);
                            console.log(blkResult)
                            res.sendStatus(201)
                        } 
                    });

                    if (chunk.length > 0) {
                        const dep = await Departed.bulkWrite(chunk);
                        console.log(dep)
                        res.sendStatus(201)
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    } catch (error) {
        next(error)
    }
})
```

Comment: i got error, it says Invalid op passed to `bulkWrite()`

Comment: also why express's response is keep saying `failed
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Comment: Forgot you are using version 4.0, that could be the reason why you getting the errors. Let me update my answer to include another solution. By the way, what is your MongoDB server version?

Comment: do you think i have to downgrade mongo's version? Well i have used 3.6 before and problem still persists.

Comment: chridam Just downgraded version to 3.6 and got error `Invalid op passed to bulkWrite()`

Comment: This may happen if an empty array is passed to the `bulkWrite()` function

Comment: i just tried passing entire results to `bulkWrite` without do chunk into several arrays. And still got same result

Comment: Ah, just found out the issue. Was pushing the wrong operation document to the chunk array, missing the key `insertOne`. Try the updated solution and let me know

Comment: i tried this one but i think one thing is wrong with this. 
    Departed.bulkWrite([
      {
        insertOne: {
          branch: req.body.branch,
          section: section._id,
          ...results
        }
      }
    ]);

Comment: `insertOne` is for only one document change or not ? @chridam

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178071/discussion-between-chridam-and-zorig).